# How to return till date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Source has

```
Date
2012-01-07
```

which is a date datatype

My target has

```
PostDate
2012-01-07 12:34:57.709
```

which is a DateTime datatype

I need to compare till date in the target to find whether both source  and target has same dates or not

Output

```
PostDate
2012-01-07
```

Comment: Please see my required output and  it is not a duplicate

Comment: this is basic SQL 101 question, and can be found by a simple search.  What you are wanting is `cast(PostDate as date)`.